# What is the difference between xterm and terminal in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, xterm

What's the difference between Terminal in Ubuntu desktop (Applications>Accessories>Terminal) and xterm? They look very similar.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The difference is that [xterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) is the standard terminal emulator of the [X Window System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System), while [gnome-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome-terminal) is the standard terminal emulator of the [GNOME project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME).

They are similar because both are [terminal emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator).

For more information about why terminals need to be emulated and what a "real" or a "virtual" terminal is read this question and answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14284/why-is-a-virtual-terminal-virtual-and-what-why-where-is-the-real-terminal.

A *terminal* is not a *shell*. To learn about the difference between a terminal and a shell read this question and answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con.

Comment: Why can't I use "setenv" command in xterm?

Comment: most likely because you are running [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) inside xterm. setenv is a [csh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) command. It appears to me that you are confusing the terminal with a shell. Learn the difference. It will help you a lot.

Comment: Well, that is what I wanted to know. Where can I find explanations about the difference of these two?

Comment: I added links to my answer. They should help you understand the differences.